# Python comparing two uneven arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to generate two arrays, `a` and `b`, each containing ~1000 random numbers. The random number are between 1 and 5.

I want to then compare each element in `a` with the corresponding element of `b` such that if `a[i] > b[i]` a variable, `counter`, will be incremented by 1. This is considered a "success". Otherwise, if `a[i] <= b[i]` nothing happens (i.e `counter += 0`). This is considered a "fail".

However, `a` and `b` can be of variable length such that both `len(a) == len(b)` and `len(a) != len(b)` are possibilities.

In the case of the latter, if `len(a) > len(b)` I'd like all the "extra" elements of `a` to automatically be counted as "successes". If `len(b) > len(a)` things should proceed normally (i.e the "extra" elements of `b` are ignored).

For example:

If `a = [1, 3, 4, 2]` and `b = [2, 4, 0]`

Then `counter = 2` because (`1 < 2`, `3 < 4`, `4 > 0`, and `2` is extra and is an automatic success`)

How would I go about doing this?

Here is some quick code, which returns the expected `list index out of range...` error:

```
import random

a = []
b = []
counter = 0

for i in range(1000):
    a += [random.randint(1, 5)]
for i in range(900):
    b += [random.randint(1, 5)]
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] > b[i]:
        counter += 1

print counter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check to see if you've run off the end of `b` in your loop:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if (i >= len(b)) or a[i] > b[i]:
        counter += 1
```

You could also be a bit more clever, and do something like:

```
for i in range(min(len(a), len(b)):
    if a[i] > b[i]:
        counter += 1
if len(a) > len(b):
    counter += (len(a) - len(b))
```

(Using `xrange` here would be a minor improvement, as well.)

Comment: This is a really good answer, short and easy to understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing that would be:

`len([_ for (i, j) in zip(a, b) if i > j]) + max(len(a) - len(b), 0)`

Comment: Why not `len([_ for (i, j)...`; no use to actually generate the tuples, no?

Comment: It's less typing for sure :)

Comment: Great answer in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Using [izip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) from itertools .This works for two lists which are not of equal length.

```
In [47]: 2>None
Out[47]: True
```

Since you need to check the greatest this works fine.

```
In [35]: from itertools import izip_longest

In [37]: lst=list(izip_longest(a,b))

In [38]: lst
Out[38]: [(1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 0), (2, None)]

In [42]: mylst=[(i>j) for (i,j) in lst]

In [44]: c=Counter(mylst)

In [45]: c[True]
Out[45]: 2
```

Comment: `None` may not be a good idea if the start integer is 0. Better it should be a negative number. so one should use `fillvalue=-1`

Answer (score 1):

A simple oneliner using `itertools.izip_longest`

```
import random
import itertools
l1 = [random.randint(1,20) for x in range(20)]
l2 = [random.randint(1,20) for x in range(25)]
sum([1 if y < x else 0 for (x,y) in itertools.izip_longest(l1, l2, fillvalue=random.randint(1,20)])
```

Here in case the lengths of the lists are not identical, `izip_longest` would generate random numbers again to fill in remaining values (but after rereading your question - it seems more correct way is `fillvalue=-1`). Basically you can use any numerical value there (or anything that can be compared with an int, if the lists are of integer types).

Comment: I think one below is more elegant, but less explicit( It's a sum of `True` values - where `True` value is equal to 1).

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.izip_longest` https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest, counting the number of situations where a is greater than b, and use a fill value for b that is less than the lowest possible a. This will result in the simplest possible control flow and most legible code. Shoot, you can ever force bools to ints with sum as here: `sum(a > b for a, b in itertools.izip_longest(a_list, b_list, fillvalue=-1))`.

Comment: Aah sorry didn't see this when I wrote the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add one more condition to check whether i's value is less than list B size

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if i < len(b) and a[i] > b[i]:
        counter += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate over the pairs like so:

```
for x, y in zip(a,b):
    # if x > y...
```

The rest can be solved just as you described, by checking the lengths:

```
counter += len(a) - len(b) if len(a) > len(b) else 0
```